# Using more than one JSON file on Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning to use some real time data on one Android Activity and another set of data on another activity. My plan is to implement this using 2 different JSON files but this seems not to be possible on Firebase.
Is there another way I can achieve this with a single JSON file?

Answer (score 5):

You could have two children inside the firebase JSON, each containing the data of your two JSON files.

```
{
  "json1":{
    //stuff
  },
  "json2":{
    //stuff2
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that

Comment: excuse me, but it doesn't work. I have 2 json file. When i replace tha contents with  // stuff, i watch: Missing project_info object